# Cannot modify managed object. Previous Value New Value

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, package, push

I promoted a package and while trying to push code to a new scratch org I get hundreds of errors similar to this one:

> Error
> force-app/main/default/objects/Real_Estate__c/fields/Furniture_Equipment_Installed__c.field-meta.xml
> Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition,
> component=00N7e0000036D30, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: Datatype
> Previous Value: Lista de selección New Value: Picklist (548:13)

There seems to be an issue with language. Previous value is in Spanish and new value is in English... not sure how this happened. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What language did you create the scratch org with?

Comment: @PhilW this last scratch org I created it with en_US language

Comment: Is that what you normally use for the package's scratch orgs?

Comment: @PhilW yes, I have not used any other language for scratch orgs

Comment: did you solve the problem?
We have the same problem today.